# Why does MUI persistent drawer content disappear in Safari when taller than screen height?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, height, persistent, drawer

This is only issue when in Safari, works great in Chrome. I have a persistent MUI Drawer and its content is taller than the screen height (tested with Lorem Ipsum text placeholder). In Chrome it will create 2nd vertical scroll bar inside that drawer, in Safari the whole drawer content just disappears. Although when I hover my mouse over the empty area I can see the components there. Any ideas how to fix that? If I remove 'persistent' it shows drawer content ok but I am loosing the menu functionality.

When content of the drawer is not taller than the screen height it shows ok, when it is taller I would expect extra vertical scroll bar to scroll to see the hidden content and not that just whole content disappears.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.